# How to control SCHEDULED indenting

Tags: org-mode

Org mode indents scheduling by default even though I don't indent my text. Can I configure it so that `org-schedule` doesn't indent?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable `org-adapt-indentation` controls the indentation relative to the outline level.  It defaults to `t`; setting it to `nil` will turn it off, with the practical effect that things like the scheduling, deadlines, property drawers, etc., will start in the first column.

Comment: Important to note here is that setting `org-adapt-indentation` to 0 (zero) and nil give different behaviors. Thank you for mentioning nil!